# Whats the best way to copy a website onto your harddrive?

Tags: wget

I like the website www.globalresearch.ca and I have made copies of it. This command works for me

`wget -r -l14 -t2 -T60 -E -k --no-check-certificate --restrict-file-names="windows,nocontrol" --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Microsoft Windows NT 5.1)" http://www.globalresearch.ca/`

but it takes something over 30 hours! to make a complete copy of the site. And It's over 6 Gigabytes in size.

Is there a better or faster way , to copy a website in gnu/linux?
Can I copy the website one time with "wget" and then use "wget"
to update the files on the hard drive and add only the new material?
I would like to have it convert the links so that they point to the files
on the hard drive ( -k ).

What would the command for something like that look like. Or is there a better way, a faster way to make a copy of the site? 
I really don't want to have to wait 30+ hours just to make a copy
of one web site.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this neat program called HTTrack.  You'll want to use one of the versions without spyware (for windows), such as 3.22-3 , if you can find it.   If you are on linux, the risk of spyware is probably reduced and the latest version might work for you.